# ImageJ - normalise stack of images to unity

Tags: image, imagej

I have a stack of images and I am trying to normalise them to unity, so that for each image the maximum is 1. How would you do it?

I'm running ImageJ on OSX, and I don't have the plugin Stacks > Normalize Stack. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "*Enhance Contrast*" function in the "*Process*" menu and tick the "*Normalize*" box. Note that it doesn't work for multi-channel hyperstacks, so you have to split the channels before, and you need to convert your stack into 32 bit mode (Image > Type > 32-bit).

To properly normalize the stack, set the percentage for saturated pixels to "0" and make sure to tick the "*Process all ## slices*" box as well.

See the [ImageJ User Guide's section about "Enhance Contrast"](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-29.html#sub%3aEnhance-Contrast) for more details.